# Upload Call/SMS logs in Android to server

Tags: android

Hi I am working on an application where it's required to upload the Call & SMS logs to server.
So I wrote a `service` for this that will run one time in a day. I can retrieve call & sms logs from history programmatically & upload it to server.

But there is no mean to upload same records tomorrow also which i did today or yesterday so how can i know i uploaded already these records only upload new records today to server ?

Do i have to create metadata or something ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of uploaded logs using a file.

1. Keep a file which contains the uploaded log entry.(Call it  `uploaded_log`)
2. While uploading the log on next day, match the log entries with the file `uploaded_log` and delete duplicate entries and upload only new entries.
3. As soon as you upload the log to server, append those entries to the file.

Comment: But it will create a problem while uploading contact when user update the contact after i uploaded it then next day how will know user has updated record so upload it again

Comment: the new contact will not be in the file, so obviously you will get to know the new entry

Comment: I took a case of when user updated contact not new entry

Comment: are you uploading the contact list also ? Or only **call/sms log** ??

Comment: If the new contact is added, how will it affect to your app. as soon as any call is made to that  number, it will be in the log and then it will be fetched with your logic to upload it to the server....I am really not getting what issue are you facing with this logic..

Comment: I want to upload contacts also & please read my question you will find what i want. You wrote same in your answer what i want but lets take a case of contact also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63747/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-williams).